# Como seleccionar aleatoriamente en python itertools.product

Tags: python

Quisiera poder realizar lo siguiente:

```
Combinaciones = itertols.product('abcd',repeat=5)
```

Acá es donde quisiera que seleccione al azar e ir eliminando cada vez que elije para no volver a pisar el mismo:

```
for i in combinaciones
```

Comment: Pasa que al realizar eso con list.....el problema q tengo es que al ser una lista realmente grande...me tira error de memoria....
entonces no se como hacer.

Comment: Conseguir las salidas de forma aleatoria no es problema, el problema es que quieres que no se repitan .Para hacer eso, en algún momento hay que guardar las salidas que vamos obteniendo para no repetirlas y si terminas usando todas las combinaciones terminarás con el mismo problema de memoria. Si solo vas a usar unas pocas combinaciones de todas las existentes si sería posible implementarlo usando un conjunto auxiliar para ir guardando las que ya aparecieron (hay que presindir de itertools y construir la función nosotros).

Comment: Seria importante saber cuantas combinaciones necesitas obtener cada  vez que usas el programa, si necesitas todas las combinaciones posibles sin repeticion o solo algunas de ellas sin repetición. Si las requieres todas la única solución que se me ocurre es usar un archivo en disco duro para almacenarlas y acceder aleatoriamente a sus lineas. Si solo necesitas unas cuantas de todas las posibles es fácil de implementar usando solo un conjunto para almacenar las que ya aparecieron.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es obtener de forma aleatoria la salida de `itertools.product` lo mas simple es usar [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) para reorganizarla  aleatoriamente:

```
import itertools
import random

Combinaciones = list(itertools.product('abcd',repeat=5))
random.shuffle(Combinaciones)

for i in Combinaciones:
    print(i)
```

Al recorrerlo con un `for` nunca vas a repetir elementos ya que en la lista no hay elemntos repetidos, podrias también crear un generador o, si realmente deseas eliminar los elementos de la lista cada vez que obtienes uno, usar `list.pop()` para extraerlos. Ya depende de para qué y cómo quieras usarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Itertools devuelve iteradores, es decir, objetos que te devuelven uno a uno los elementos. Crearé una función que se quede el elegido entre los actuales:

```
def choice_iterator(it):
    choice = next(it)
    n=1
    for i in it:
      n+=1
    if random.random() > 1 / n:
       choice=i
    return choice
```

Es fácil ver que la probabilidad de que la probabilidad de ser seleccionado cada uno de los números del iterador dado es la misma:

```
def randomCombinacion(*args,**kargs):
    return choice_iterator(itertools.product(*args,**kargs))
```